# NFC Mifare Ultralight bogus response data

Tags: ionic-framework, nfc, capacitor, mifare

I am using PhoneGap-NFC with Ionic/Capacitor and am trying to lock a NXP NTAG213.

According to the datasheet (https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) I have to write to page 0x2B to set the PWD, page 0x2C for the PACK.

```js
const set_password_cmd = Uint8Array.from([
    0xA2, //WRITE
    0x2B, //address 2B
    1, 2, 3, 4//pwd
]);
let res = await nfc.transceive(set_password_cmd);

const set_pack_cmd = Uint8Array.from([
    0xA2, //WRITE
    0x2C, //address 2C
    2, 7, 0, 0//pack
]);
res = await nfc.transceive(set_pack_cmd);
```

Password should be 1234, pack should be 27.

Problem is I keep getting 0xA (LF) as a response to both commands and the tag does not lock itself.

PS. I am calling .connect(tech) and .close() afterwards inside a addTagDiscoveredListener call, sending a GET_VERSION command works as expected and returns correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that just setting a Password and Pack does not enable password protection by default, you also need to tell it what parts of the card to protect.

The default value of the `AUTH0` byte (the fourth byte of page 0x29h on ntag213) is set to `0xFFh` which means no pages are protected by the set password (See table 11 in Section 8.5.7 in the datasheet)

> AUTH0 defines the page address from which the password verification is required. Valid address range for byte AUTH0 is from 00h to FFh. If AUTH0 is set to a page address which is higher than the last page from the user configuration, the password protection is effectively disabled

So you probably want to set the `AUTH0` byte to a value of at least 0x4h (start of the user data area) or lower to enable password protection.

You should also check that that `PROP` access bits on page `0x2Ah` for ntag 213 are set to your needs as the default is only to password protect `write access`

Comment: Thats what I was mystified about, i'm fine with read being allowed, writing is what I want protected and I suppose setting AUTH0 to page 0 will be sufficient?

Comment: Yes `AUTH0` to page zero should password protect everything from being written to.